# Instantiating a new object everytime a filter is hit

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I have an application which needs to query a database every time a particular page is hit.

I have implemented a filter for this page. The filter does the querying, sets a attribute and then passes the request to the jsp.

The database is queried through an object. At the moment, I am instantiating a new object everytime the filter is hit.

Is there a way around this? Can I create a single object which can be reused?

Inside the doBeforeProcessing method, I have this:

```
    doBeforeProcessing(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
        ServletContext ctx = this.getFilterConfig().getServletContext();
        String status = (new GetData()).getStatus();
        ctx.setAttribute("msg",status);
    }
```

My main bother is whether creating a new object every single time the right approach. Because, eventually I will be using the same approach for a quite few other pages and I am concerned about memory issues.

Comment: I assume you're using Java? Java EE 5, 6, 7? What code have you so far?

Comment: Singleton pattern I guess :-/

Comment: database queried using which object? are you talking about jdbc connection object or any persistence object..please post code for more clearance..you can create singleton depending on ur context..

Comment: @Harry (and just in case) - Servlet filters are already singletons.

Comment: What does your object actually *do*? Is it thread-safe? Do you have any reason to suspect that creating a new instance on each request is actually causing a problem? (I'd strongly suspect not - the database access is going to be the killer.) Your question is too vague to answer at the moment.

Comment: Is the new object an instance of `GetData`?

Comment: yes. the new object is a new instance of GetData.